# Scale images correctly in toolstrip C#

Tags: c#

In my application I have a toolstrip with some buttons on it. I set ICO images from my computer as image sources for those buttons' Image property. The buttons look great when the toolstrip is set at 16x16. However, when I set it to something else like 24x24, the icons look blurry... I don't know why this happens, as my ICO files have also 24x24, 32x32, 48x48 and even 64x64 sizes... Please point me to the right direction: what image format to use/how to make the icons look normal. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use some other format? Like PNG? I don't even know if it's possible, but I know that ICO images are always nasty.

Comment: I tried with bigger PNGs, but C# down scales them and they look way more bad than the 16x16 native ICOs (or PNGs, I have 16x16 PNGs too)...

Answer (score 0):

Based on my recent research, I believe the default ToolStripItem does NOT support multi-image ICO's, it just takes the smallest one and treats it as an Image.  So, as you resize, it is just scaling the smallest Image in the ICO rather than taking the appropriately-sized Image from the ICO.  I believe that is by-design.  Please correct me if that is wrong.

I believe this project gives you one that supports multi-image ICO's properly, but I have NOT tried it yet... so, I can't testify it is a solution.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27012/Multiple-Image-Sizes-for-ToolStrip-Items